# POST from angular.js doesn't work but directly from form works. Why?

Tags: angularjs, post, express, passport.js

I'm working on basic authentication for my project in node.js using passport.js and it's LocalStrategy method. It's even without password validation yet. Accounts are stored in MongoDB instance.

I was stuck for whole day when in course I'm going through instructor recommended binding form data to angular and sending `$http.post()` from there, like so:

```
$scope.signIn = function (username, password) {
    $http.post('/login', {username: username, password: password})
        .then(function (res) {
            if(res.data.success) {
                console.log('Logged in');
            } else {
                console.log('error logging in');
            }
        })
};
```

And here's the route for it:

```
app.post('/login', function (req, res, next) {

    var auth = passport.authenticate('local', function (err, user) {
        if(err) { return next(err); }
        if(!user) { res.send({success: false, user: user}); }

        req.login(user, function (err) {
            if(err) { return next(err); }
            res.render('index', { success: true, user: user });
        });
    });

    auth(req, res, next);
});
```

Except it ALWAYS returned with { success: false, user: false }. After ton of googling I've decided to make a POST request directly from form:

**JADE:**

```
.navbar-right(ng-controller='navbarLoginCtrl')
form.navbar-form(action='/login' method='post')
    .form-group
        input.form-control(name='username' placeholder='username', ng-model='username' required)
    .form-group
        input.form-control(name='password' type='password', placeholder='password', ng-model='password' required)
    button.btn.btn-default(type='submit' value="Submit") Sign in
```

as opposed to:

```
.navbar-right(ng-controller='navbarLoginCtrl')
form.navbar-form
    .form-group
        input.form-control(name='username' placeholder='username', ng-model='username' required)
    .form-group
        input.form-control(name='password' type='password', placeholder='password', ng-model='password' required)
    button.btn.btn-default(ng-click='signIn(username, password)') Sign in
```

Submit approach actually works but i'd like to keep things clean and do it with angular. 
**How can I do it?**

*Other passport.js components for reference:*

```
var User = mongoose.model('User');

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    if (user) {
        done(null, user._id);
    }
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {

    User.findOne({_id: id}).exec(function (err, user) {
        if(user) {
            return done(null, user);
        } else {
            return done(null, false);
        }
    });
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function (username, password, done) {
        User.findOne({username: username}, function (err, user) {
            if (user) return done(null, user);
            else return done(null, false);
        });
    }
));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check what your browser send.

Your broswer form send data in the form username=&password=, angular post them in JSON {username:, password:} and the Content-Type header is different.

If you want to do the same in angular :

```
 var headers={ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'};         
      return $http.post(BackEndpoint+'/login','username='+username+'&password='+password,
    {headers:headers}).then(function(result){
});
```

This is what i use against spring authentication.

Comment: thanks, that did the trick. Shame, that there's absolutely no mention of it anywere, even passport.js docs. I just assumed that body-parser would take care of that for me. 

Any idea why it works in earlier versions of Express/node without explicitly specyfing content-type?

Comment: Absolutely no idea i just know the difference about form posting and angular posting :)